# Finite-difference of the derivative at an arbitrary location

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences

The second-order, centered-approximation, finite difference of the derivative of $f(x)$ at $x$ is:
$$
f'(x)=\frac{-f(x-\Delta x)+f(x+\Delta x)}{2\Delta x}
$$
**Question:** Suppose we have the value of $f'(x)$ throughout our finite-difference grid with grid spacing $\Delta x$. Let $f'(x_0)$ be such a value at $x_0$. Is there a way to find $f'(x)$ at an arbitray location between $(x_0-\Delta x,x_0+\Delta x)$ based on the value of $f'(x_0)$?

**Attempt:** I tried linearly interpolating the value of $f'(x_0)$ between $(x_0-\Delta x,x_0+\Delta x)$. However, the result was incorrect.

Comment: What do you mean "the result was incorrect"? What did you do, and what is the correct answer?

Comment: Why do you think this is "second order"?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Because the error is proportional to $(\Delta x)^2$. This is taken from my textbook, too.

Comment: So what is a "first order" method?  (And $0$th order?)

Comment: @Andrei The way I performed interpolation is: I let $f'(x)$ at $x_0-\Delta x$ to be the maximum value, and $f'(x)$ at $x_0$ to be half the max value. I also assumed that $f'(x)$ is linear between $(x-\Delta x_0,x+ \Delta x_0)$.

I don't know the correct result, but the result that I obtained didn't make sense in a bigger problem that I am working on.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork:First order: either
$$
f'(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(x - \Delta x)}{\Delta x}
$$
or
$$
f'(x)=\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}
$$

I am not sure of the zero-order approximation. I am not sure we even have such an approximation.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Your formula is the second-order approximation of $f''(x)$. I am referring to $f'(x)$ in my question.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for an approximation to $\ f'(x). \ $ Using simple algebra the answer is
$$ f'(x) \approx \frac{ f(x_0+\Delta x) - f(x_0-\Delta x) }{2 \Delta x} +
  2(x - x_0)\frac{ f(x_0+\Delta x) -  f(x_0) + f(x_0-\Delta x) }{ \Delta x^2} $$
where the two fractions are approximations to the first and second derivatives of $\ f(x) \ $ at $\ x = x_0. \ $
You can check that when $\ f(x) \ $ is a quadratic polynomial, then the approximation is exact.